# Kill runaway Phusion Passenger child processes with monit?

Tags: phusion-passenger, monit

Is there any way to monitor and kill Phusion child processes that are using too much memory or cpu with monit?

There are many examples for Apache, but since Phusion runs in its own process, runaway Rails threads do not trigger the monit rules for Apache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to monitor and kill Phusion child processes that are
>   using too much memory or cpu with monit?

It is a symptom of application leaking memory. I would rather fix the source of problem rather than expecting a tool to monitor and kill processes.

That said, [Passenger Enterprise](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) ( non-free product ) has the option to automatically kill the appserver process and respawn when the application reaches a certain amount of memory.

Note: I do not have any affliation with Phusion, the creator of Passenger. I'm just an user of their Enterprise product.